# MeteorJS HTTP POST Request Connection Lost XMLHttpRequest

Tags: python, rest, http, meteor

I am writing an application that integrates into a website that is already written in Meteor (I can't change that but I can add on to it). I am trying to send information from the Meteor application to my Flask server.

To do this I am using MeteorJs's HTTP module.

The code for this:

```
HTTP.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/path', {
    "content" : {"headers" : {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, "data": {time: getTime, data: getData()}}
}, 
(error, result) => {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        console.log({time: getTime(), data: getData()})
        }
    else {
        console.log(result);
        }
    }
)
```

`getTime()` and `getData()` both work independently outside this function, so they shouldn't be the source of error.

When I look at the JS console for when the event is being fired I receive the following message:
`Error: Connection lost at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystateexchange` and what was supposed to be sent to the Flask server.

When I look at the Flask server I see that it is receiving the post request with status code 200, but it seems like there is no data actually being received.

The code on the python end:

```
@app.route(r'path', methods=["POST"])
def get_data():
    print(request.data)
    print(request.args)
    return "Hello World"
```

The print statements come out empty with this being shown on the console `b'[object Object]'` or `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

The Meteor app and the Flask app are both on different ports.

The problem I believe is on the MeteorJS side, since I used the curl linux function it works properly when I ping the flask server from there.

Is there a way to fix this error? If so how?

Comment: Can you confirm, that the request is working when coming from another source than your meteor app (for instance a command line tool or similar)?

Comment: The request works when I use curl

Answer (score 0):

Hi "parameters" should be "data".
You can find all valid options in [the docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call).
Let me know if it works for you.

```
HTTP.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/path', {
        data : {time: getTime(), data: getData()}
    }, (error, result) => {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            console.log({time: getTime(), data: getData()})
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: If I use data then the server receives OPTIONS requests and does not transmit any data.

Comment: Sounds as if you are at least making some progress. The options request is sent to find out information from the server. just a thought this isn't a cors issue is it? You could test out by testing from a browser with security disabled I found a post here with some methods you could use to test it out. https://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-bypass-cors-errors-on-chrome-and-firefox-for-testing/

Comment: Alternatively just add cors support for flask if you haven't already https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/